# Is the optimization problem right?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

If we want optimize the following problem
$$
\min_x \{a(x)+c(x)\}
$$
and we have
$$
a = \min_y b(y)
$$
then, could we directly optimize the following problem?
$$
\min_x \{b(x)+c(x)\}
$$

Comment: If $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ then the first optimization problem has the minimum value simply $-\infty$ and for the second problem too the answer seems to be $-\infty$.

Comment: Hi, @SamratMukhopadhyay, thanks a lot for reolying! I've been reading some papers on optimization. I found in some proofs in these references, and it seems to be known to all that the optimization relations above in the pose is right. But I think I'm confused. I'm not sure if the optimization technique is about the relaxation technology. It seems many optimization methods are optimizing the supremum and infimum from some inequalities.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay, sorry, I've made a mistake. I've updated the post, could you please help check it please?

Comment: Are $a, b$ and $c$ functions?  What is the variable in your first optimization problem?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking the following: Consider the problem
$\min_{x\in X}\big(a(x)+c(x)\big)$, given that $a(x)=\min_{y\in Y} b(x,y)$. Is this equivalent to solving $\min_{x\in X,y\in Y}\big(b(x,y)+c(x)\big)$? Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @Rahul, yes, you're right. They are functions.

Comment: @littleO, thank you, I've updated the post, please help check it.

Comment: As the problem is written now, with $a = \min_y b(y)$, $a$ doesn't actually depend on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The last problem has solution $$\min_{x}c(x)+a$$ Now you need to find $\min_x c(x)$, but I do not see any way it can be found only from $\min_x a(x)+\min_x c(x)$ if you have no other information.